# how to calculate square root using floating point registers

Tags: assembly, x86

```
fild st, [eax]
fsqrt
fistp [eax]
```

with the code above, I thought I'd be calculating the square root of the value that resides in eax, and then store the square root in eax too. The code does not work. (doesn't assemble) How do i need to change it in order for it to work correctly?

the error message 'illegal immediate' shows up twice.

EDIT: correction, code does not compile

Comment: I'm surprised that even assembles, since `[eax]` is ambiguous. You are not reading and writing from/to `eax`; you're reading and writing from/to the memory location pointed to by `eax`.

Comment: `[eax]` is a memory operand, so it refers to the value `eax` points to, not `eax` itself.

Comment: BTW what assembler are you using?

Comment: `fild` only takes one operand, and it has to be memory.  Pushing onto the x87 stack is implicit.  Try compiling C that does what you want to see how to get an integer function arg into x87 (or preferably into an XMM register for SSE2 `sqrtsd`, so you don't need to bounce through stack memory)